# "I love you" door hanger in hotel. Is it meant seriously?

Tags: hotels

I stayed in a hotel that had the usual door hanger with "Do Not Disturb" but the backside had "I love you" on it. Is this actually used to communicate something to the staff or just a joke?

*inb4: "To tell them that you love them."*

Comment: Care to explain why, in which way, it could be a joke?

Comment: Because this is the only explanation I could come up.

Comment: It's just for fun.  No big deal.  You'd leave it, say, on the bed so your wife could read it.   That's all - no big deal!   Just BTW what country was this?

Comment: @Fattie: Thailand

Comment: I have seen much weirder signs in Thailand.  For example, a sign by the pool which said: "In case of an accident, check for signs of breeding".

Comment: @badjohn - In that case it seems there's a different kind of accident going on ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°).

Comment: @badjohn such a sign wouldn't be unusual in Japan. :)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yes, I have seen some wonderful Japanese signs.

Answer (score 2):

No, not serious and not a secret code for the hotel, staff, simply humorous and, perhaps, a bit was lost in translation from บอกพวกเขาว่าคุณรักพวกเขา (for which Google Translate offers "Tell them you love them").

Comment: What's the significance of "บอกพวกเขาว่าคุณรักพวกเขา"? Is it something like a common phrase or recognised saying?

Comment: @user568458, the back of the "Do Not Disturb" sign often says "Service Room Now" or something equivalent to that. The sign may be showing a bad translation of the Thai equivalent for that.

Comment: Just to be clear: "บอกพวกเขาว่าคุณรักพวกเขา" means "Service Room Now" in Thai?